# java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve API configs with status: 404 when called from webserver

Tags: google-app-engine, webpack, google-cloud-endpoints, webpack-dev-server

So I have an appengine webapp which includes cloud endpoints deployed locally on port 8888.

The error message in the title occurs on startup of our [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html) which runs on port 3000 and proxies all requests starting with `/_ah/api/*` to `http://localhost:8888`. The exact console error is as follows:

[image]

The odd thing is, when I open this url in another tab and switch the port to 8888 the request comes through, and the webpack-dev-server can also proxy the requests to the backend from then on.

Most other issues I read on this suggested setting the appengine config in gradle to the following:

```
httpPort = 8888
httpAddress = "0.0.0.0";
```

However I already did that so that does not seem to be the issue.

My relevant webpack config is as follows:

```
module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  ...
  output: {
    ...
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/'
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
    proxy: {
      '/_ah/api/*': 'http://localhost:8888/'
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some backends don't work properly without `changeOrigin: true`. You can use it like this:

```
proxy: {
    '/_ah/api/*': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8888/',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work, does the proxy path (`/_ah/api/`) need to be included in the request? You could try if ignoring the path works:

```
proxy: {
    '/_ah/api/*': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8888/',
        ignorePath: true
    }
}
```

And if that doesn't work, I would try out removing the last part of the proxy path: `/_ah/api/*` to `/_ah/api`. This should do the same, but the first one is deprecated.

Comment: Cheers! using `changeOrigin` worked, didn't even need the `secure:false`, I'll give you the bounty once I'm able to